# Return values from subprogram

Tags: python, return-value, subroutine

I've created a subprogram called DEVICE_ON in which I've defined some of these statements

> ```
>                        if j == 2:
>                             print('shutdown')
>                             # Run command.
>                             ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(shutdown)
>                             var_colonna_2=data_array[i][j]
>                             return var_colonna_2
> ```

var_colonna_2 is a string value (could be "X" or "V") and in this subprogram I have 8 return value (one for each var_colonna)

Now in the main programm I'm calling another subprogramm defined as:

> CHECK_TEST(var_colonna_1, var_colonna_2, var_colonna_3, var_colonna_4,
> var_colonna_5, var_colonna_6, var_colonna_7, var_colonna_8)

this CHECK_TEST of course is executed after the DEVICE_ON.
So basically In the main programm I have something like:

> DEVICE_ON(ssh,data_array, i, j)

> CHECK_TEST(var_colonna_1,var_colonna_2, var_colonna_3, var_colonna_4,
> var_colonna_5, var_colonna_6, var_colonna_7, var_colonna_8)

I was expecting that, since in DEVICE_ON, I've defined the return value for var_colonna_x (x=1 to 8), automatically the value of each var_colonna was updated and received from CHECK_TEST for internal computation,but right now it always sees 0.

I've also tried with the debug.It seems that the values are passed, but I still don't get why they are not seen in the next subprogram.

[image: return_picture_debug_mode]

Answer (score 0):

I've understand where my mistake was.
Basically the retur function is ok but in the main I was missing something like:

```
var_colonna_1=CHECK_TEST(var_colonna_1, var_colonna_2, var_colonna_3, var_colonna_4, var_colonna_5, var_colonna_6, var_colonna_7, var_colonna_8)
```